# How to write multiprocess queues in Laravel 4.2 (having supervisord configured)?

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, laravel-4.2, laravel-queue

I have a website, where users can export reports in CSV format. When they click "Export" button, I add a new row to my database table indicating that there is a new request for report generation.

I want to set database access for 2 processes because 1 is not enough. My current supervisord configuration is the following:

```
    [program:csv_export]
    command=php /var/www/mywebsite.com/artisan queue:listen --tries=1 --timeout=3000 --queue=csv_export
    numprocs=2
    process_name=csv_export_%(process_num)02d
    directory=/var/www/mywebsite.com/
    stdout_logfile=/var/log/mywebsite/csv_export.log
    autostart=true
    autorestart=true
    stopsignal=KILL
    loglevel=debug
    redirect_stderr=true
```

My queue `fire()` code looks like this:

```
public function fire($job, $data){
    $reports = \CSVReport::where('status', '=', CSVReport::CSVNEW)->take(1)->get();

    foreach ($reports as $key => $value){
        // prepare data and file
        $value->status = 'done';
        $value->save();
    }

    $job->delete();
}
```

I'm using Laravel 4.2, an upgrade is not possible yet. I want to avoid a situation when two processes would access the same table row in a database. How can I avoid that in my queue class?

Comment: Queue automatically process job one by one : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues

Comment: @MayankDudakiya I know it, that's why I want to fire this work in two separate processes. Does your answer mean that in supervisord configuration numprocs=2 will not have any effect in my case?

Comment: i gues you may try to rewrite queue manager to get only odd or even rows in queue table based on process name

Comment: @michail1982 thank you, good idea! But will it be processed concurrently?

Comment: @tohhy of caurse no, but each process will not see jobs belongs to other process (odd/even)

Comment: @michail1982 thank you, I'll try to implement that.

Comment: Personally I would prefer the approach that put a unique id (CSVReport name + timestamp OR CSVReport ID if you can get it) in the Job and the Database, so each Job will access only his CSVReport. The Job should not be processing blindly, it should be assigned a very specific task.

Comment: Then if you do that, you can also add 2 supervisord queues `[program:csv_export_1]` and `[program:csv_export_2]`, and then you would choose randomly (50-50) to send it to `--queue=csv_export_1` or `--queue=csv_export_2`, specifying each time the queue name inside the Job with method `$this->onQueue('csv_export_1');` or `$this->onQueue('csv_export_2');`

Comment: @KeitelDOG Sometimes I have 10 entries in my database table waiting to be processed. If I add two supervisord configurations, will it be a good approach to process rows with odd ID via the first queue and with even ID via second?

Comment: Sorry, you don't have to create 2 supervisord queues config. The numprocs = 2 will treat them in parallel.

Comment: @tohhy forget about 2 supervisord conf. And about the even/odd approach. Can't you just pass the CSVReport ID as attribute to the Job `protected $csvID;` and pass the ID value in constructor, and then Select that CSVReport with `$reports = \CSVReport::find($this->csvID);` ?

Comment: The way you're implementing it is like Job 100 caused by Client asking for CSVReport ID 100 could be treating CSV Report ID 95 instead of 100. Passing a CSVReport ID will ensure that Job 100 will only treat CSVReport 100.

Comment: @KeitelDOG Yes, I can do it.

Comment: @KeitelDOG thank you very much! I'll try to implement everything the way you described. I'll let you know after a few days about the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you push your Job in queue like :

```
$csv = new CSVReport;
// $csv->... = ...;
$csv->save();
Queue::push('ExportCSV', array('csvID' => $csv->id));
```

Job fire method uses `$data` parameter to pass specific values to make sure the Job do something specific. Now in ExportCSV job, in fire method :

```
public function fire($job, $data){
    $report = \CSVReport::find($data['csvID']);

    // prepare data and file
    $report->status = 'done';
    $report->save();

    $job->delete();
}
```

This way each Job will have the CSVReport ID serialized in his $data, and at the time supervisord will execute it, the Job will only process his specific CVSReport ID in the database.

You can still check for status done if whatever a case could process them outside queues :

```
public function fire($job, $data){
    $report = \CSVReport::where('status', CSVReport::CSVNEW)->where('id', $data['csvID'])->first();

    // prepare data and file
    if($report) {
        $report->status = 'done';
        $report->save();
    }

    $job->delete();
}
```

Comment: I would like to ask: what are the guarantees that two processes will not process the same csvID simultaneously? Sometimes it could happen when two processes access to a database at the same time and get the same id. Am I wrong? I just don't understand the mechanism how it works.

Comment: @tohhy when you call `$csv->save();`, MySQL or Database System assigns an auto-incremented `id` to the record in `csv_reports` table. Then you call `Queue::push('ExportCSV', array('csvID' => $csv->id));` which assign that id to the Job permanently. Any other CSVReport saved at the same time will get a different `id` than the others because of Database auto-incrementation never assigns the same `id` twice, even if the transaction failed to complete. This way, it's ensuring that ONLY 1 SINGLE JOB can access to ONLY 1 SINGLE CSVReport record.

Comment: @tohhy which Database System are you using? MySQL, SQL Server? Oracle? NoSQL type? MySQL, SQL Server and Oracle should be ok

Comment: I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: Thank you, I have implemented this in my system and everything works great. :)